# Implementing Insertion/Deletion/QueryRange in a Region-Quad tree?

Tags: javascript, data-structures, geospatial, region, quadtree

When you're using a quad tree to store regions instead of just points, how exactly should your implementation change? I can't find a good source code example on the web of how one might implement a PR-QuadTree. The only examples I can find are of point quadtrees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the wikipedia article  the region quadtree holds a bitmap with the full region at each level and the point quadtree holds the convex hull with 4 points.